# How to query for models containing all given values in an array field? [Doctrine ORM and ODM QueryBuilder]

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, query-builder, odm

Given model `Post` which has a field `tags` which holds an array of strings, eg:

```
Post:
  id: 1
  tags: ['a', 'b', 'c']

Post:
  id: 2
  tags: ['a', 'z']
```

How to construct a query, to get models containing all values from array `['a', 'b']` (in this example, return only Post id 1)?

I've been thinking about these:

Useing Doctrine ODM QueryBuilder:

```
// is this correct?
$qb->expr()->field('tags')->all( array('a', 'b') );
```

Useing Doctrine ORM QueryBuilder:

```
$qb->expr()->all( /* the docs say to use DQL here.. is there no QueryBuilder alternative? */ )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was misled by the `array` type mapping name. If you read carefully the docs, you will learn that there is no such database type as `array`.

So what type is `array` mapped to? The anwser is `text`. Which means you can do `LIKE` operations on it (although, these may cause some performance impact).

So, to anwser my own question, to achieve such goal I'd have to construct something like:

```
$qb->where($qb->expr()->andX(
    $qb->expr()->like('tags', '?1'),
    $qb->expr()->like('tags', '?2'),
    $qb->expr()->like('tags', '?3')
))->setParameters(array(
    1 => '%"a"%',
    2 => '%"b"%',
    3 => '%"c"%'
));
```